# Como puedo terminar mi slider automatico con cada imagen con un enlace

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema con el slider de un html que estoy creando, no estoy muy iniciado en estos temas, así que puede que la solución sea fácil. Quiero hacer un slider automático que cada 4 segundos pase a otra imagen, esto lo he conseguido con el siguiente código:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container img');
var currentIndex = 0;

function showNextImage() {
  var currentImage = images[currentIndex];
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
  var nextImage = images[currentIndex];

  currentImage.classList.add('fade-out', 'active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentImage.classList.remove('active');
    currentImage.classList.remove('fade-out');
    nextImage.classList.add('active');
  }, 1000);
}

showNextImage(); // Mostrar la primera imagen

setInterval(showNextImage, 4000); // Mostrar la siguiente imagen cada 4 segundos
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.slider-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-container img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider-container img.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-container img:first-child.active {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f00" alt="Imagen 1">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0f0" alt="Imagen 2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/00f" alt="Imagen 3">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/ff0" alt="Imagen 4">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0ff" alt="Imagen 5">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f0f" alt="Imagen 6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi cosa es, alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto mismo, es decir, que vayan pasando las imagenes. Que cada imagen tenga un enlace, y al pincharle a la imagen, te mande a su enlace correspondiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nota: el código con la solución está al final de la respuesta. Esto es una descripción paso a paso de cómo se hizo para que sirva de ayuda y referencia si estás empezando.

Si lo que quieres hacer es que cada imagen sea un enlace, debes envolver cada imagen dentro de un [elemento `<a href="ENLACE">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (donde `ENLACE` será una ruta a la que quieres enlazar).

Esta parte del código:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f00" alt="Imagen 1">
<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0f0" alt="Imagen 2">
<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/00f" alt="Imagen 3">
<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/ff0" alt="Imagen 4">
<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0ff" alt="Imagen 5">
<img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f0f" alt="Imagen 6">
```

Pasaría a ser algo como esto:

```
<a href="#1"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f00" alt="Imagen 1"></a>
<a href="#2"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0f0" alt="Imagen 2"></a>
<a href="#3"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/00f" alt="Imagen 3"></a>
<a href="#4"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/ff0" alt="Imagen 4"></a>
<a href="#5"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0ff" alt="Imagen 5"></a>
<a href="#6"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f0f" alt="Imagen 6"></a>
```

Ahora, en el JavaScript, en lugar de seleccionar las imágenes, seleccionamos los `<a>` que los contienen. Así, en lugar de:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container img');
```

tienes que hacer esto:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container a');
```

> Nota: he mantenido el nombre de la variable `images` por simplicidad, pero te recomiendo que lo cambies. Ya no contiene imágenes sino enlaces y puede crear un poco de confusión si otra persona (o tu yo futuro) lee el código.

Finalmente, como tienes un elemento envolviendo las imágenes, deberías cambiar el CSS para darle estilos al enlace. Lo bueno: sólo necesitas que tenga los mismos estilos que el elemento `img`. Y, cómo ahora se le da la clase "active" al enlace en lugar de la image, cambiar un par de selectors. Estas son las reglas que cambian (sólo los selectores, no el contenido):

```
.slider-container img {
  ...
}

.slider-container img.active {
  ...
}

.slider-container img:first-child.active {
  ...
}
```

que pasarán a ser:

```
.slider-container a,
.slider-container img {
  ...
}

.slider-container a.active,
.slider-container a.active img {
  ...
}

.slider-container a:first-child.active {
  ...
}
```

---

Con esos cambios, el código quedará así:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container a');
var currentIndex = 0;

function showNextImage() {
  var currentImage = images[currentIndex];
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
  var nextImage = images[currentIndex];

  currentImage.classList.add('fade-out', 'active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentImage.classList.remove('active');
    currentImage.classList.remove('fade-out');
    nextImage.classList.add('active');
  }, 1000);
}

showNextImage(); // Mostrar la primera imagen

setInterval(showNextImage, 4000); // Mostrar la siguiente imagen cada 4 segundos
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.slider-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider-container a,
.slider-container img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider-container a.active,
.slider-container a.active img {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-container a:first-child.active {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <a href="#1"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f00" alt="Imagen 1"></a>
    <a href="#2"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0f0" alt="Imagen 2"></a>
    <a href="#3"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/00f" alt="Imagen 3"></a>
    <a href="#4"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/ff0" alt="Imagen 4"></a>
    <a href="#5"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/0ff" alt="Imagen 5"></a>
    <a href="#6"><img src="https://placehold.it/1000x500/f0f" alt="Imagen 6"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```